# Is there a way to get manpages on a Windows machine, apart from online manpages?

Tags: windows, manpages

Is there a way to get manpages on a Windows machine, apart from online man pages?

I have a suggestion: if in some way I can get all the manpages in a text format (still don't know how), put them in a directory and then get the index for each with Google Desktop, or even built-in window-indexing. I think it shall do what's necessary.

Is there any better alternative?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Stackoverflow: [Where is the ‘man’ Program for Windows (Program to open UNIX man pages)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944434/where-is-the-man-program-for-windows-program-to-open-unix-man-pages)

Answer (score 1):

You could run linux in a VM, run a co-linux instance, or ssh into a linux box i suppose.

Comment: I am already doing that, grml in virtualbox, but the point is, it kills the over productivity, capture mouse, pickup ur hands press the the rt-ctrl key. I was looking for something as convenient (ctrl+shift+T - to open the new window) and then type man abc.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the cygwin suite for windows.
http://www.cygwin.com/

Answer (score 0):

*If* you also run a Linux server somewhere, you could create a (read only) Samba share to `/user/share/man` and connect to that share from your Windows PC. This makes indexing and searching that drive by Google Desktop very easy.